# Toggle div by triggering and image click mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am currently working with the toggle div function. I am using images to be the triggering point for toggling. For example when a div is close an image with a "plus" signs appears to indicate the user to expand and vice versa for compressing the div. The only issue is that I am using two sets of images for expanding and compressing divs but I can only get a set to work but not both. The is example I have doesn't work well in jsfiddle but if you like to look at it there here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/sQnd9/4/

Here is my example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle1(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
        imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Plus_Circle.png"/>';
        
        }
        else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/Minus_Circle.png"/>';
                
        }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function toggle2(showHideDiv2, switchImgTag2) { 
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv2); 
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag2); 
        if(ele.style.display == "block") { 
                ele.style.display = "none"; 
        imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src=images/arrow_open.png/>'; 
        } 
        else { 
                ele.style.display = "block"; 
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src=images/arrow_close.png/>'; 
        } 
} 
</script> 


<div><a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle1('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="images/Plus_Circle.png";/></a>Example</div>  
<br />
       <div id="contentDivImg" style="display:none;">
       Example1-Content
       </div>


<div><a id="imageDivLink2" href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2', 'imageDivLink2');"><img src="images/Plus_Circle.png";/></a>Example2</div>  
<br />
       <div id="contentDivImg2" style="display:none;">
       Example2-Content
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't your code (other than the mistakes that @appclay pointed out). The problem is `jsfiddle`. Just look at the source code it produces. When you put anything in the "javascript" section it's puts it in it's own namespace, preventing access to those function names outside of that block (so your call to `toggle1` for example was throwing an undefined function error).

You can see this in action by defining these functions directly as `window.` properties. Then your code works as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/sQnd9/7/

In your own code, you presumably would not encapsulate these function names into their own scope, and it would work as expected (but note again that you should make the changes @appclay pointed out).

Also, you probably shouldn't be doing it this way anyway. You should attach the event handlers in the javascript block.

Comment: Another `jsfiddle` problem... Half the times I see a question with a jsfiddle reference, the problem turns out to be jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes on the img src attribute in the second one

You're also referencing the first function in both examples, so the second function never gets called... Try changing:

```
<div><a id="imageDivLink2" href="javascript:toggle1('contentDivImg2', 'imageDivLink2');"><img src="images/Plus_Circle.png";/></a>Example2</div>
```

to

```
<div><a id="imageDivLink2" href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2', 'imageDivLink2');"><img src="images/arrow_open.png" /></a>Example2</div>
```

Also, I don't know why you have semicolons in your img tags, they shouldn't be there.

Comment: This is true, but does not answer his question. Even with those fixes, it still doesn't work. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @BenLee, I was thinking this might be the cause of it not working, although it's more likely the fact that the second toggle function is not being used anywhere, `a#imageDivLink2` is referencing the first toggle function.

Comment: these are good points and arguably more useful to the OP than my answer, even if technically not the complete answer in this case. +1 (note that when I posted my first comment your answer was not as fleshed out).

Comment: It was a mistake when i was writting the code. Fixed the errors but it is still not working.

Comment: jonthecoder2346, perhaps try @BenLee's suggestion in his answer - it's a jsfiddle problem.  This is one of those fine moments when the workman gets to blame his tools! :)

Comment: @appclay I figured out what was the issue. Thank you sir, I did follow your suggestion. Ben Lee's answer was accurate. The mistake was in my part on not explaining myself clearly. Either way here is my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sQnd9/13/